# Integers appearing as characters in file in C

Tags: c

Here is a segment of my code, it should create an array of 10 random integers, print them to a file, it then puts them in order and appends the ordered array to the file,

How do I stop the integers appearing as ascii characters in the file?

```
size=10;
int nums1[size];
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    nums1[i]=rand();
}

FILE *fp;
if((fp=fopen("ARRAY_1", "w"))==NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open file.\n");
}
if(fwrite(nums1, sizeof(int), size, fp) != size) {
    printf("File read error.");
}
fclose(fp);

bubblesort(nums1,size);

if((fp=fopen("ARRAY_1", "a"))==NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open file.\n");
}
if(fwrite(nums1, sizeof(int), size, fp) != size) { 
    printf("File read error.");
}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: You mean you want to convert them to strings?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot expect text in the file if you use fwrite and write binary data with it. Use fprintf instead or ofstream (C++).

Answer (score 1):

`fwrite` will just call `fputc` which outputs the specified byte to the specified file. When you open this file in your text editor, it will interpret that data as ASCII codes. You can check the actual contents of the file using a command like [od](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?od) (for Linux) or [Debug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_%28command%29) (for Windows) to display various representations of the data in that file.

If you want the actual integer to appear as a character in your text editor, use `fprintf`:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if(fprintf(fp, "%d ", nums1[i]) < 0) {
        /* An error occurred */
    }
}
```

`fprintf` will work like you expected because it *converts* the argument (i.e. `nums1[i]`) to the format specified as the second argument.

For example, consider

`fprintf(stdout, "%d", 1);`

Here, `fprintf` will take the number 1 and convert it to its ASCII equivalent (ASCII code is 49 in decimal) and output that ASCII code to stdout.

Comment: "It then converts that to a printable character and outputs that to the specified file." No, `fputc` just writes a byte, whether that denotes a printable character or not.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Yes, absolutely. I worded that wrong. I edited my answer now to better explain what is happening. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Yes, much better. I don't think it's necessary to mention `fputc` at all here, saying that `fwrite` just writes the bytes from memory to the file would be enough, but it doesn't harm.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Yes true :) But I have come across people who claim `fwrite` magically writes binary data. I just wanted to demystify that function haha

Answer (score 0):

You're just writing the array as a binary chunk of data out into the file.

If you want to output the elements of the array you will need something like `fprintf(fp, "%d", nums[i]);` in a loop.

Comment: -1, I think that is the exact opposite of what the OP wants, since that would save the numbers as strings.

Comment: @unwind, To my mind if a newbie says they want "integers printed to a file" then they want the integers stringified, not as a binary dump. ICBW though, only the OP can clarify....